# define a terminal that is a subset of ID in xtext

Tags: xtext

I would like to to create a terminal that is somewhat can be matched to ID, but not fully. 
While ID is

```
terminal ID         : '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```

the terminal I would like to define is

```
terminal TYPE: (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*)?
```

because TYPE can match ID I am getting RULE_ID errors, what can I do in that case?

```
______EDIT__________

Domainmodel :
    (elements+=XType)*;

terminal TYPE: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;

MyID: 
    TYPE | ID
;

XType:
    DataType | Entity;

DataType:
    'datatype' name=MyID;

Entity:
    'entity' name=MyID ('extends' superType=[Entity])? '{'
        (features+=Feature)*
    '}';

Feature:
    (many?='many')? name=MyID ':' type=[XType];
```

Model (base on the blog example)

```
datatype String

entity Blog {
    title: String
    title2: String
    many posts: Post
    many Posts: Post
}

entity HasAuthor {
    author: String
}

entity Post extends HasAuthor {
    title: String
    content: String
    many comments: Comment
}

entity Comment extends HasAuthor {
    content: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a Datatype rule

```
MyID: ID | TYPE;
```

And a value converter for MyID and use that at the places you used ID

Or you forget type and do the check for the restricted range inside the validator

```
Domainmodel :
    (elements+=XType)*;

terminal TYPE: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;

MyID: 
    TYPE | ID
;

XType:
    DataType | Entity;

DataType:
    'datatype' name=MyID;

Entity:
    'entity' name=MyID ('extends' superType=[Entity|MyID])? '{'
        (features+=Feature)*
    '}';

Feature:
    (many?='many')? name=MyID ':' type=[XType|MyID];
```

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by Or you forget type and do the check for the restricted range inside the validator

Comment: just have one terminal ule called ID that unifies your TYPE and ID and then do the restrictions my validating the attributes you assign ID to or having a datatype rule TYPE: ID with a IValueConverter that throws ValueConverterExceptions on bad inputs

Comment: have a look at the validator xtext pregenerates it has a rule for names of greetings start with a Upper Case Letter although ID would allow lower case letters as well

Comment: I did the following ```terminal TYPE: (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*)?
;

MyID: ID | TYPE;
```

and got several errors, including [ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: XtextGenerator)
am I doing somethign wrong ?

Comment: do you mean ```terminal TYPE: (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*) ;```

Comment: Yes sorry about this typo, but also while the generation of xtext is completing, when I invoke it as an eclipse application, with the blog example I am still getting - missing RULE_ID at 'Post'

Comment: can you share complete grammar and model

Comment: well you have to adapt the other places you use ID as well ```xxx=[YYY]``` is short for ```xxx=[YYY|ID]``` which means ref ```YYY``` and parse ```ID``` => ```xxx=[YYY|MyID]```